unable to process injected variables in js script using dart
the goal is for dart to run a js script.
the issue is that i am not able to insert parameters for the js script to recognize in a dynamic manner.
i am able to add parameters if i hard code the data (see code).
for some reason the function is being treated as a string i think,
i added the outputs aswell::
  Map<String, dynamic> params2= {
      "current": {
        'sys_id': '776cd316-d46c-41b2-9cb7-7767dd170dcb_1716219681941',
        'sys_application_id':
            '3db9ab81-59cd-427f-88be-fa8998a087f7_1716219673200',
        'sys_updated_by': 'f590f44d-4c97-4230-b5fa-32c00bd5c5f8_1716219673200',
        'sys_active': true,
        'sys_roles': ['1aca6190-c53d-48b8-b114-1bbedec95fe1_1716219673200'],
        'sys_created_on': '2024-05-20T15:41:21.000+00:00',
        'sys_table_id': 'bff01a71-10b2-40cb-be6f-08b2da722d28_1716219673200',
        'sys_description': 'System configurations',
        'sys_updated_on': '2024-05-20T15:41:21.000+00:00',
        'sys_hint': 'System configurations',
        'sys_created_by': 'f590f44d-4c97-4230-b5fa-32c00bd5c5f8_1716219673200',
        'sys_title': 'System'
      }
    };

    // the following code does not work
    print("PRINTING PART OF THE CODE THAT DOES NOT WORK:\n");
    params2['gs'] = {
      "print": (dynamic p) {
        print("printing gs: ${p}");
      }
    };
    String jsCode = """
console.log(current.name);
gs.print("Hello from Dart!");
""";
    params2.forEach((key, value) {
      print('key: $key: \nvalue:$value');
      js.JsObject data = js.JsObject.jsify(value);
      js.context[key] = data;
    });
    js.context.callMethod('eval', [jsCode]);

    // the following code works::
    print("PRINTING PART OF THE CODE THAt WORKs!!!:\n");

    // Define Dart maps for objects
    var current = {"name": "juan"};
    var gs = {
      "print": (dynamic p) {
        print("printing gs: ${p}");
      }
    };

    // Convert Dart maps to JavaScript objects
    js.JsObject jsCurrent = js.JsObject.jsify(current);
    js.JsObject jsGs = js.JsObject.jsify(gs);

    // Set JavaScript variables
    js.context['current'] = jsCurrent;
    js.context['gs'] = jsGs;

    // Execute the JavaScript code
    js.context.callMethod('eval', [jsCode]);

this is the output::

evaluate_script()

PRINTING PART OF THE CODE THAT DOES NOT WORK:

key: current: 
value:{sys_id: 776cd316-d46c-41b2-9cb7-7767dd170dcb_1716219681941, sys_application_id: 3db9ab81-59cd-427f-88be-fa8998a087f7_1716219673200, sys_updated_by: f590f44d-4c97-4230-b5fa-32c00bd5c5f8_1716219673200, sys_active: true, sys_roles: [1aca6190-c53d-48b8-b114-1bbedec95fe1_1716219673200], sys_created_on: 2024-05-20T15:41:21.000+00:00, sys_table_id: bff01a71-10b2-40cb-be6f-08b2da722d28_1716219673200, sys_description: System configurations, sys_updated_on: 2024-05-20T15:41:21.000+00:00, sys_hint: System configurations, sys_created_by: f590f44d-4c97-4230-b5fa-32c00bd5c5f8_1716219673200, sys_title: System}
key: gs: 
value:{print: Closure: (dynamic) => Null from: p => {
          core.print("printing gs: " + dart.str(p));
        }}
null
printing gs: Hello from Dart!
PRINTING PART OF THE CODE THAt WORKs!!!:

juan
printing gs: Hello from Dart!


i didnt find a similar stackoverflow.
