running js code in dart to perform calculations
the goal is to run a js script in dart(conditions2),
in the js script i need to perform some logic and get the data(current) out,
conditions2 should update current and then to access the updated current in save.
how do i do that?
 static evaluate_script(String condition, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    print("evaluate_script()\n");
    // Define Dart maps for objects

    String conditions2 = "current.name = 'pecker';\n current.save() ";
    var gs = {
      "print": (dynamic p) {
        print("printing gs: ${p}");
      }
    };

    params['current']['save'] = () {
      print("SAVE!");
   // access update current here
    };

    // fix: make dynamic
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78512372/unable-to-process-injected-variables-in-js-script-using-dart

    // Convert Dart maps to JavaScript objects
    js.JsObject jsCurrent = js.JsObject.jsify(params['current']);
    js.JsObject jsGs = js.JsObject.jsify(gs);

    // Set JavaScript variables
    js.context['current'] = jsCurrent;
    js.context['gs'] = jsGs;

    // Execute the JavaScript code
    js.context.callMethod('eval', [conditions2]);
  }

this worked isolated but it does not work in my code:
var a = {
  "b": "b",
  "save": function() {
    // Accessing the object using "this"
    console.log(this);
  }
};

// Calling the save method
a.save();

